Question on counterexample to one of exercises
One of the exercises state if $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}$ is a finite Galois extension and the valuation ring in $\mathbb{Q}_p(\alpha)$ (this is also the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p(\alpha)$) is $\mathbb{Z}_p[\alpha]$ for all primes $p$, then the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.
My question is why is the following not a counterexample. Let $\alpha = \frac{1-\sqrt{7}}{3}$. Note $\alpha$ is not in the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$, so the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is not $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. However, if we choose $\sqrt{7}$ to be the solution to $x^2-7=0$ in $1+3\mathbb{Z}_3$ (which exists by Hensel), then $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_3$. If $p\ne 3$, I showed that the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p(\alpha)$ is also $\mathbb{Z}_p[\alpha] = \mathbb{Z}_p[\sqrt{7}]$. Why is this not a counterexample to the exercise? The issue has to do with the $p=3$ case.
Edit: I change my interpretation to the following:
The integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Q}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is $\mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$

It is not a counterexample because it does not satisfy the hypothesis. The element is not integral locally at $3$, so in particular is not integral at all primes.
